# Does "solve the confusion" look good in written English?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I looked up [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solve+confusions%2Cclear+up+confusions%2Csolve+problems&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and saw the usage of "solve the confusions" is really low. But on the web there are plenty examples.

Comment: You will find lots of bad English on the web. Try changing the verb to 'resolve'.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. 'resolve' sounds better. How does it compare to 'clear up the confusions'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably better ways to express your meaning than "solve the confusions".

Firstly, "confusion" is nearly always an uncountable noun, so it should be singular.  If you feel that plural is more appropriate in your case, it might be because you actually should say "solve the problems".  Many of the examples encountered on the web are from non-native speakers who really mean "solve the problems"

However if there really is "confusion", you might say "resolve the confusion", or perhaps "clear up the confusion" or even "eliminate the confusion"